# Does this javascript code reliably tell apart relative from absolute URLs?

Tags: javascript, html, url

Should I expect any pitfalls if I would simple do this

```
function absoluteOrRelative(url)
{
  return url.indexOf(":") === -1 ? "relative" : "absolute";
}
```

The reason I ask is that I am uncertain if there is any way in which a colon character `:` might also occur in a relative URL?

Some URLs contain a so called "[URI schemas](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/294588/what-is-a-uri-scheme)", such as `data:`,`ftp:`,`mailto:`,`blob:`,`file"`, and many more. While I feel uncertain if all of the possible schemas really imply the meaning of what constitues an URL, I would hope that the above code does "work", as any absolute URL to the most common `http`, `https`, `file:` schemas seems to be dealt with appropriately as well.

Comment: Honestly, it depends on the meaning of "relative" and "absolute"; it appears as though your meaning says that if the URL has a scheme it is "absolute", but others would say that "//example.com/path" is an absolute URL...

Comment: Using `//google.com` is a legitimate way to use an absolute URL, it just avoids specifying the protocol as the default usage is http.

It is also possible to have a url contain `:` in the query string.

In short, no, that is not reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a more reliable way to determine this is to use the [built-in URL interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) to construct a couple URL objects and compare origins.

```
return new URL(window.location).origin === new URL(url, window.location).origin;
```

This allows the browser to parse and figure all this out for you.

Comment: thank! I will give it a try, this is really the kind of answer I was looking for, i.e. a way to robustly tell apart the realtive from an absolute ULR. However should I also consider the effect that the presence of a `<base>` element might pose to your code?

Comment: `return new URL(document.baseURI).origin === new URL(url,document.baseURI).origin`